# Fastest way to render hundreds of ellipses, constantly updating, on ipad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, core-animation, calayer

The two approaches I'm thinking of are

1) One CALayer per dot
2) One CALayer drawing all of the dots

As I use the accelerometer, the dots all change color. I'm using a timer to update the colors, and have overridden drawInContext to draw the current color (interpolation of two colors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For hundreds, I would draw to one layer (or flip between two) for efficiency.  If that isn't smooth enough, OpenGL is the next option to look into.